# MySQL: strange behaviour using UNION, MAX and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a simple table that stores messages:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------------+------+
| id | sender | receiver |      dt      | text |
+----+--------+----------+--------------+------+
| 1  | a      | b        | ..19.26.00.. | msg1 |
+----+--------+----------+--------------+------+
| 2  | c      | b        | ..19.26.02.. | msg2 |
+----+--------+----------+--------------+------+
| 3  | b      | a        | ..19.26.03.. | msg3 |
+----+--------+----------+--------------+------+
```

I want to select the most recent message in a conversation. For example, for b I want:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+
| conversation |  MAX(maxdt)  | text |
+--------------+--------------+------+
| ab           | ..19.26.03.. | msg3 |
+--------------+--------------+------+
| cb           | ..19.26.02.. | msg2 |
+--------------+--------------+------+
```

so I use this query:

```
SELECT conversation, MAX(maxdt), text FROM
(SELECT CONCAT(sender, receiver) AS conversation, MAX(dt) AS maxdt,  text
FROM message
WHERE receiver='b' GROUP BY conversation
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT(receiver, sender) AS conversation, MAX(dt) AS maxdt, text
FROM message
WHERE sender='b' GROUP BY conversation) AS x
GROUP BY conversation
```

but the result is:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+
| conversation |  MAX(maxdt)  | text |
+--------------+--------------+------+
| ab           | ..19.26.03.. | msg1 |
+--------------+--------------+------+
| cb           | ..19.26.02.. | msg2 |
+--------------+--------------+------+
```

So, the datetime value is correct but the text comes from the wrong tuple!

Any suggestions? [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80e6c/4)

Comment: That is the order in which the text fields are listed in the table; GROUP_CONCAT(text) and you should see

Comment: You'll want to join back to that table to get the appropriate `text` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have a possible solution, working SQL fiddle. Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('b',other) AS conversation, text, dt AS maxdt FROM 
(
    SELECT IF(sender='b',receiver, sender) AS other, dt,  text
    FROM message
    WHERE (receiver='b' OR sender='b') order by dt desc
) 
AS TBL group by other
```

if you want the conversation field standardized you can just CONCAT ('b', other) as conversation.

Comment: I edited it to standardize the conversation variable and make aliases more sensible

Comment: The use of `text` and `dt` in the `select` clause uses an extension of MySQL described here (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).  Note that the documentation *explicitly* warns against using it when the values are not the same for all rows within a group.  And it clearly states that an *indeterminate* value is used.  In other words, although the query might work it clearly is using unsupported features in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT CONCAT(sender,receiver) AS conversation,maxdt,text 
     FROM
         (SELECT max(dt) as maxdt FROM message WHERE sender = 'b'
            UNION
          SELECT max(dt) as maxdt FROM message WHERE receiver = 'b')T1,
          message T2
     WHERE T1.maxdt = T2.dt
     AND (T2.receiver = 'b' OR T2.sender = 'b')
```

[sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48bfc/8/0)

Comment: I thought wrong. I thought you wanted the latest message where b is a sender UNION with the latest message where b is the receiver